# Windows 10 apps from store fail to update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store-apps, windows-store

When inside the Windows 10 Store, I have 30+ applications that need to be updated. However, all apps show an **Error: See details** message and the update doesn't succeed. When I click on the **See details** link on any of the apps, the following message pops up:

> Something unexpected happened
>
> Reporting this problem will help us understand it better. You can wait
>   a bit and try again or restart your device. That may help.
>
> Code: 0x80246008

I can either **Report this problem** or **Close**

I have reported the problem but this doesn't solve anything immediately, of course. I've tried the following:

- Restarting Windows
- Reset the Windows Store with **WSReset.exe**
- Run Windows 10 updates

It's important to also note that when I attempt to do any Windows Updates, they also fail so I suspect this is related. When I go into **Windows Update Settings**, I have a message that says:

> We're having some trouble downloading updates. Restarting your device
>   may help.

Of course, restarting hasn't resolved anything. What I have done to attempt to fix this issue is go to the Windows Catalog online and lookup the latest KB number for the latest updates and manually updated successfully. However, both the **Windows Updates** and **Windows Store Updates** continue to fail

Comment: Could you try solutions in [Fix Windows Update issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10164/fix-windows-update-errors)?

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT After my original post, I found that link and went through all of the resolutions when its suggested previous one would not solve the issue. I didn't get anywhere so I contacted MS. Their tech went through the same steps and obviously failed so he escalated to a higher level tech that should be calling today. I'll post back after that call.